# Data not displaying from website hosted on AWS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am facing very weird problem.Please help.

I have developed website using MEAN stack and it is hosted on aws ec2 instance.
If I access that website from my laptop, I can see the data(from mongodb installed on server) in my website.But at the same time when I access the website from some other laptop or say mobile phone(using browser), all the tables are coming blank without any data.

I am not getting, why It is working on my laptop as there is no relation between aws instance and my machine.Except that I use their console/dashboard from my machine.

Thanks.

Comment: Please try to debug issue using firebug.

Comment: Look at the HTML being returned to each computer, and figure out the differences from there. Your browser will have an "inspect" capability, or worst case look at View Source.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this.I have found the issue and it is not related to db.I am also using elasticsearch which sends it's search result to db and somehow that is not working on server.I need to check for that.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you set your laptop host file while developing the website to resolve to the AWS EC2 instance IP where your website is hosted.

Or check the EC2 instance security group if you have opened the HTTP port of the instance just to your IP address.

As above 2 are the only causes that might give the issue mentioned by you.